# Why is this legal? Referring to a constant in a type, from an attribute *on* the type, without prefixing with type name?

Tags: c#, attributes, constants

Look at the following [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
void Main() { }

[TestAttribute(Name)]
public class Test
{
    public const string Name = "Test";
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
[Serializable]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute(string dummy)
    {
    }
}
```

This compiles without a hitch. Why?

Specifically:

```
[TestAttribute(Name)]
public class Test
{
    public const string Name = "Test";
```

Why don't I have to write this:

```
               vvvvv
[TestAttribute(Test.Name)]
public class Test
{
    public const string Name = "Test";
```

Is the attribute declaration deemed to be "inside" the type, and thus in scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of an attribute instance declaration is indeed that of the type on which it is attached, or (in the case of a method, parameter, etc.) the type containing the element on which it is attached.

I can't find anything specific on that, though the standard does say:

> Attributes can be specified at global scope (to specify attributes on the containing assembly) and for type-declarations (§16.6), class-member-declarations (§17.1.4), struct-member-declarations (§18.2), interface-member-declarations (§20.2), enum-member-declarations (§21.1), accessor-declarations (§17.6.2), event-accessor-declarations (§17.7), elements of formal-parameter-lists (§17.5.1), and elements of type-parameter-lists (§25.1.1).

While it doesn't explicitly say anything about class scope, it does differentiate that from the wider scope of global attributes in "global scope".

I'd note that the CIL of your class would be:

```
class public auto ansi beforefieldinit SomeNamespace.Test extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .custom instance void SomeNamespace.TestAttribute::.ctor(string) = (
    01 00 04 54 65 73 74 00 00
  )
  .field public static literal string Name = "Test"
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil managed
  {
    .maxstack 8
    ldarg.0
    call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    ret
  }
}
```

The scoping in CIL is much clearer than in C#

Answer (score 1):

When you put the `TestAttribute` on the class it associates it with that class so the `Name` field would be in scope.

You can read all about Attributes and how they work here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664611(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Where specifically does it say that the attribute is in scope of the class?

Comment: You are adding an attribute to the class, so your scope is not based on the attribute but instead is based on the class you add it to(in this case `Test`) the documentation isn't very specific about this, but it can be found to be that way through testing.