# Why do I have to parent-type-qualify to use a nested type when inheriting from a generic type?

Tags: c#

Consider this:

```
[SomeAttr(typeof(Bar))]
class Foo {

   class Bar {

   }
}
```

...and this:

```
class Foo : ISomething<Bar> {

   class Bar {

   }
}
```

The first example compiles, the second doesn't. To use a nested type reference when inheriting from a generic type I must qualify it with the parent's type name:

```
class Foo : ISomething<Foo.Bar> {

   class Bar {

   }
}
```

My question is, why? and why doesn't this restriction apply when referring from an attribute in the parent type (first example)?

Comment: My guess would be that the compiler processes the class attributes after it compiles the classes? But I don't know enough about the compiler internals to even know how to find/prove that answer. Very interesting question though!

Comment: What is a practical example of using a public nested child class in this way? Why have a nested class when the parent class is dependent on the child vs. Just making it a class in the same namespace as the parent?

Comment: @BateTech I found this limitation when working with a code generator that only allows me to inject code inside a class, to define my own methods.

Comment: Is it possible to add "using YourNamespace.Foo;" at the top, and will it compile using the non-attribute option in that case? I'm guessing that won't work but I'm not at my computer right now to check.

Comment: @BateTech You cannot import a type, at least not in the current version of C#.

Comment: Sorry most of my work projects are in vb.net and I know there you can import a class if that class contains static/shared methods, but I don't think you can if that class is defined within the file you are trying to do the import (was a long shot). But sounds like Baldrick gave a great answer. Hopefully his answer helps you out in your situation with the code generator.

Comment: BTW Interestingly VB.NET has chosen the opposite scoping here (without adjusting the Namespaces available): `<DebuggerTypeProxy(GetType(Testing.SubClass))>` requires the `Testing.` but `Implements IProgress(Of SubCLass)` does not.

Comment: @MarkHurd That's very interesting, I was able to confirm. I think VB behavior is more intuitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all about the *scope* of the declaration. Consider the following code:

```
namespace FooSpace
{
    class Foo : ISomething<Bar> 
    {
        class Bar { }
    }
 }
```

The line of code `class Foo : ISomething<Bar>` is in the `FooSpace` namespace, but *not* inside the class `Foo`. At this point, `Bar` has no meaning. `Bar` by itself would only have a meaning *within* the scope of the `Foo` class itself.

To use the class `Bar` in any code *outside* the *Foo* class, you have to qualify it as `Foo.Bar`. This rule also applies *within the class declaration itself*.

Why is it this way? Couldn't the complier automatically work out that you must mean the nested `Bar` within the same class?

Well, for one thing there could potentially be other nested classes called `Bar` within other classes in the same namespace, as follows:

```
namespace FooSpace
{
    class Foo : List<Foo.Bar>
    {
        public class Bar { }
    }

    class Foo2 : List<Foo2.Bar>
    {
        public class Bar { }
    }
}
```

Without the qualifier, which `Bar` do you mean? The compiler would have no way to tell. So it's much more consistent for the compiler not to try and guess, but to insist on an explictly qualified class name.

As for the attribute case, although a class-targetting attribute is *declared* above the class declaration like this:

```
 [SomeAttr(typeof(Bar))]
 class Foo { ...
```

in reality, the compiler translates this to something more like this:

```
class public auto ansi beforefieldinit FooSpace.Foo extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .custom instance void FooSpace.SomeAttr::.ctor ... etc.
```

In other words, the actual `SomeAttr` attribute object is created *inside* the class, using the parameter you supply. This parameter `typeof(Bar)` is of course then valid, as it exists within the class scope of `Foo`.

The related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119258/why-is-this-legal-referring-to-a-constant-in-a-type-from-an-attribute-on-the) discusses this case too.

It's interesting to note that exactly the same rules and behaviours apply to class attributes which access const or static class members - you don't need the specify the class name, because the attribute is actually created *inside* the class.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but doesn't answer why the attribute on the parent class with a reference to class "bar" compiles successfully.

Comment: Note your hand waving that the attribute is actually placed inside the class when viewed in IL doesn't really explain why the scope is different for C# purposes.

Comment: @MarkHurd: Agreed. Unfortunately, the C# spec doesn't have much to say on this. It seems clear to me that the Attribute *is* scoped within the class - but as to *why* (as in design motivation), I'd be glad if anyone could improve my answer with that information.